# How to remove extra line after the last tab in Divi Builder

Tags: css, divi

I built a tab section using Divi Builder but I'm struggling to remove a border below line at the end of the tabs.

I did add;

```css
border: none;
ouline: none;
```

all border lines were removed but the below line is still there.

[image]

how can I remove that line?

Comment: Rather than snippets of code, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul.et_pb_tabs_controls:after { 
  border: none !important; 
}
```

This works, but needs to be added in Custom CSS for specific page or in divi theme. Doesn't work in module Custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code to your *child theme* **or** *divi theme options -> custom css* **or** *in a code module in the page you want to apply this*:

`ul.et_pb_tabs_controls:after { border: none !important; }`

Comment: You should explain a little bit more the answer. Does the `!important` is really needed?

Comment: The use of !important is need it because the border wont been removed. I have test it before I place it in a public sight.